# OData v4 Web API XML response nesting too deeply

Tags: c#, xml, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I am building an OData Web Service using WebAPI and OData v4.

Imagine I have two entities I want to expose through my service: Student and Teacher.

Now a Student has a Teacher as one of its properties and a Teacher has many students.

I was able to get the service to return XML using the trick:

```
IList <ODataMediaTypeFormatter> oDataFormatters = ODataMediaTypeFormatters.Create();
config.Formatters.InsertRange(0, oDataFormatters);
```

However the XML formatter seems to want to format everything. What I mean is when I ask for a Teacher, it returns to me also their students. The issue thus arises of an infinite loop as then each of the student has a teacher and the teacher has students, etc. I get a stack overflow exception.

I have tried the solution proposed here of http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#handling_circular_object_references but I still somehow get a stack overflow exception.

To get around this issue I have had to basically cut the loop saying that a Teacher doesn’t have Students anymore so that the loop is cut and stack overflow doesn’t occur anymore. However, this removes Students as a navigation property of the Teacher.

Is there a way to tell the formatter to simply respond with its properties, excluding navigation properties, without completely ignoring the property through the use of the attribute [IgnoreDataMember] (i.e. don't nest)

Comment: maybe this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19668964/web-api-2-xml-serialization-is-ignoring-metadatatype

Comment: Can you give us more detail sample codes?